# Regression score with metric as an argument in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am looking for sklearn solution to get regression score without knowing metric beforehand so I can do something like

```
score = regression_score(y_true, y_pred, metric="mean_squared_error")
```

right now I am using multiple if statements and calls to different functions that looks ugly, e.g

```
if metric == "mean_squared_error":
   score = sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)
if metric == "neg_mean_squared_error:
   ...
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, you mean be able to save a variables based on iterable performance criteria?

Comment: @CeliusStingher no it means I do not want to call different functions for different metrics, but rather call one function with variable argument.

Comment: I think it doesn't look ugly necessarily... how could this be made more elegant if it's already wrapped in a regression_score and then neatly called in your actual code?

Comment: Hi, @YohanRoth, if you think the below answer was appropriate, I kindly request you to accept it as a verified answer, since it helps other users who might look into this in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `getattr` to load the required function. Please use the modified function below:

```
import sklearn.metrics

def regression_score(y_true, y_pred, metric):
    function = getattr(sklearn.metrics, metric)
    return function(y_true, y_pred)
```

> SAMPLE OUTPUT

```
import numpy as np
y_true = np.array([2,3,4,1])
y_pred = np.array([1,3,1,2])

regression_score(y_true,y_pred,"mean_absolute_error")
1.25

regression_score(y_true,y_pred,"mean_squared_error")
2.75
```

So basically you just have one function without the `if` conditions which will do your job.